# Integrating Seamless telegram login into grammy js

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, grammy

I would like to integrate the [Seamless telegram Login](https://core.telegram.org/api/url-authorization) into my bot using [grammy js](https://grammy.dev/) library but couldn't find any way in docs. Has anyone worked on it?